# Recording video of selected portion of desktop in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am building a C# application and I don't know how to crop area of  desktop and record video and show that video in picture box using C#. Please help me. Appreciate every bit of help!

Update
Below is my code:

```
 bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height); 
 gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp); 
 gr.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left,bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
 gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
 pictureBox2.Image = bmp; pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Comment: Show some code, what have you tried till now?

Comment: i tried whole screen but dnt knw how to select area . my code is:    bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
            gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
           // gr.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left,bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

            pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;